# Trying to find index of the table row of a td element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the table rowIndex from a td element in jQuery. This is what I'm trying:

```
var element = $('td').filter(function() { 
    var Text = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(Text, 10) == some_Textvar;
});
var parent = element.parentNode;
var index = parent.rowIndex;
```

I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowIndex' of undefined(…)

html:

```
<div class="class1">
    <table class="class2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            ......
```

The element definitely exists because I work with it in the rest of my code. How can I get this row which this td element is in?

Thanks

Comment: Post your `html`.

Comment: @Kinduser edit made with html :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` is jQuery object which doesn't have `parentNode` property thus it be `undefined` so error is expected.

Use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)/`[0]` to get the reference of underlying DOM element, then you can access the property.

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

```
var parent = element.get(0).parentNode;
var index = parent.rowIndex;
```

As an alternate, Using jQuery you can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements

```
var index = element.parent().index();
```

Comment: I see, when I log the index to the console, I was expecting a number: 0,1,2 etc. Instead it returned a function ( elem ) {

  // No argument, return index in parent.....
I'm very confused as to what this is...

Comment: @RuthYoung, Did you tried `element.parent().index()`?